# He could be released next year

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider this sentence, please:

1. *He was jailed five years ago and **could** be released next year*.

Can I say that sentence 1) has *two interpretations* depending on the the degree of stress placed on "could"? For example:

a) With **unstressed** "could":

It means that the authority have the legal right to release him early, so they **could** do it **if** they so chose.

b) With **stressed** "could" (speculation):

It means his release **may possibly** happen next year, and it is interchangeable with "might":

*He was jailed five years ago and **might** be released next year*.

Is this correct?

Comment: Both the alethic (there's a chance he will be released) and the deontic (the rules as they stand allow for his release) senses of 'could' are available no matter how much the modal is stressed.

Comment: You mean it is the context that determines which of (a) and (b) is intended, and stressing the modal verb does not have much to do with this. Am I right?

Comment: ..........................Yes.

Comment: One last question: Do we use the "alethic" *could* commonly in place of "might" for **predictions/speculations** about the future (as in sentence (1) in the OP) or about the present (as in: A: Where is John? B: I don't know. He **could** be in the market.)?

Comment: ... Yes indeed. Probably more often than 'might'.

Comment: Just curious, does the "alethic" *could* work in place of "might" in conditional sentences too? For example: *If you don't hurry, you **may/might/could** miss the train.* Or is "could" different from "might" in that example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the prisoner has been sentenced to a period greater than five years but is eligible to be considered for parole after six years.

Exactly what that means in terms of his sentence, the percentage of the term he must serve before being considered for parole, the actions he must avoid taking while incarcerated and the degree of rehabilitation he must demonstrate before being granted parole will all depend on the jurisdiction under which he is being held (and possibly the nature of the crime he has committed).

The reason that his release on parole is uncertain is that his actions while in gaol or his inadequate degree of rehabilitation might persuade the parole board not to grant parole.

No matter what the level of stress on the word 'could' it can be considered as synonymous with 'might' in this case.

Comment: I'm a little confused: Do you agree that a) and b) are two **different** interpretations and do not imply the same thing? If so, do you agree that "might" is not possible with interpretation a)?

Comment: @Mr. X You're confused yet accept the answer?

Comment: @Mr.X I thought that my final paragraph made it clear that the level of stress on the word 'could' makes no difference to the the interpretation. I'm sorry if that is not the case. In terms of the two interpretaions you give in the question the first provides the conditions under which the second one becomes possible, there really is only one set of circumstances in this case so I don't see that there is any conflict, or even any difference in the interpretations. In other circumstances this might not be true but, even then, it doesn't matter whether 'could' is stressed or not.